# Seeking Open source Tools for GML in ArcGIS and gvSIG?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, software-recommendations, gml, gvsig, inspire

I’m searching open source tools for ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 and gvSIG 2.4 to load and write complex GML data for example INSPIRE GML.

I have not the possibility to install interoperability or INSPIRE extension for ArcGIS and I’m looking for other solutions.

gvSIG instead read GML file but doesn’t write them, I found the extension for INSPIRE cadaster data but I need something for more general topics.

Comment: You'll need ArcGIS for INSPIRE for complex schema.  You could look at GeoServer app schema, or deegree as opensource alternatives

Comment: If you don't fear command line use ogr2ogr https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html with this https://gdal.org/drv_gmlas.html.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking whether there are tools that already exist for these two software, otherwise I'll think to different solutions (as the ones you propose)

Answer (score 2):

as you say gvSIG writes GML, but on the Schema for Spanish Cadastre. At this video (in Spanish) you can see how to do it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1l3ufwJVRi4

I don't know if it will be useful for you.

There are some parameters for Spanish Cadastre specifically, but you probably can edit the GML file later with a Text editor and remove these parameters. The other ones are general (area, coordinates...)